# failure importing data with h2o and R

Tags: r, h2o, data-import

I'm learning h2o with R and Python (using a virtual machine with Linux). In order to do that, i tried the following code, but the data import failed.

```
loan_csv <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan/master/data/loan.csv"
data <- h2o.importFile(loan_csv, destination_frame = "loanD")
```

And the error is
"Error in h2o.importFolder(path, pattern = "", destination_frame = destination_frame,  : 
  all files failed to import"

Someone can give me a hint?

Comment: include a complete runnable program.

Comment: it works on my machine. check if your vm has internet access.